# genealogytree marriage label position

Tags: genealogytree, genealogy

I am using the genealogytree package to make a sandclock construction, but I am also shifting the edges connecting married couples up so that they are level with the center of the nodes. I am using options for distance, disconnect, and extra edges to get the layout I want and all works well, but I do not know how to shift the label with the marriage date. Is there a simple option to do that in this situation? I am including a screenshot of what I have and the code that produces it. I would like the 1850 to be shifted up just above the line connecting Father and Mother.

[image: sandclock graph with shifted edges]

```
\begin{genealogypicture}[template=signpost,
 options for family={fam1}{extra edges={Fa,Mo}{C2} 
 {yshift=12mm}},
 options for family={fam2}{extra edges={GF,GM}{Fa} 
 {yshift=-13mm}}] 
 sandclock
 {child[id=fam1,family database={marriage={1850}{}}] 
    {g[id=Fa,male,disconnect]{Father} p[id=Mo, 
    female,distance=1cm,disconnect]{Mother} 
    child{g[id=C1,male]{Child1}}  
    child{g[id=C2,male]{Child2}} 
    child{g[id=C3,female]{Child3}}  
    }
  parent[id=fam2]{g[id=GF,male]{Grandfather} } 
  parent{g[id=GM,female,distance=1cm,disconnect] 
  {Grandmother}}
 }
 \end{genealogypicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `label options={fill=white},` to block out the green lines

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,
label options={fill=white},
options for node={A}{box={colback=blue!30}},
options for node={B}{box={colback=green!30}},
options for family={AB}{label={\gtrsymMarried  2006}}
% show id,
]{
child[id=AB]{
g[id=A]{Father}
p[id=B]{Mother}
c[id=c1]{Child 1}
c[id=c2]{Child 2}
c[id=c3]{Child 3}
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT1

Optionally you could center the marriage label between the parents by using--

```
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror,raise=2pt},
line width=1pt,yshift=0pt] (A.south east) -- (A.north east)
node [align=center,right=10pt,midway,fill=yellow] {{\gtrsymMarried  2006}};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=2pt},
line width=1pt,yshift=0pt] (B.south west) -- (B.north west);
```

The left brace is placed by the code--

```
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror,raise=2pt},
    line width=1pt,yshift=0pt] (A.south east) -- (A.north east)
```

The right brace is placed by the code-- the command `mirror` is removed to reverse the brace face

```
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=2pt},
line width=1pt,yshift=0pt] (B.south west) -- (B.north west);
```

The marriage label is placed with help of --

```
node [align=center,right=10pt,midway,fill=yellow] {{\gtrsymMarried  2006}}
```

The complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,
label options={fill=white},
options for node={A}{box={colback=blue!30}},
options for node={B}{box={colback=green!30}},
options for family={AB}{label={\gtrsymMarried  2006}},
% show id,
options for node={B}{distance=2cm},
]{
child[id=AB]{
g[id=A]{Father}
p[id=B]{Mother}
c[id=c1]{Child 1}
c[id=c2]{Child 2}
c[id=c3]{Child 3}
}
}
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror,raise=2pt},
line width=1pt,yshift=0pt] (A.south east) -- (A.north east)
node [align=center,right=10pt,midway,fill=yellow] {{\gtrsymMarried  2006}};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=2pt},
line width=1pt,yshift=0pt] (B.south west) -- (B.north west);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The nodes `Father Mother`have been separated by 2cm

### EDIT2

The marriage without braces -- simply delete the 2 draw commands and substitute

[image]

```
\draw (A.east) node [right=10pt,fill=yellow] {{\gtrsymMarried  2006}};
```

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,
label options={fill=white},
options for node={A}{box={colback=blue!30}},
options for node={B}{box={colback=green!30}},
options for family={AB}{label={\gtrsymMarried  2006}},
% show id,
options for node={B}{distance=2cm},
]{
child[id=AB]{
g[id=A]{Father}
p[id=B]{Mother}
c[id=c1]{Child 1}
c[id=c2]{Child 2}
c[id=c3]{Child 3}
}
}
\draw (A.east) node [right=10pt,fill=yellow] {{\gtrsymMarried  2006}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This completely solved my problem, thanks. To have the marriage label centered between the parents without the braces, I am using \draw (A.east) node [align=center, xshift=6mm, yshift=2mm] {{\gtrsymMarried  2006}};
where the xshift and yshift can be manually adjusted. Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: edit provided to the solution above