# genealogytree: How to use braces as the standard connection style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, trees, genealogytree

How can I use a curly brace (in black) as the standard connection style in genealogytree? 
That means:
*How to change the default* (which is these green lines).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[box={colback=white}]{
parent{
g{first child}
c{second child}
c{third child}
p{father}
%p{mother}
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Hint 1:** I am not a family tree expert, but I guess in terms of this manual example (p. 211) the style has to change somehow like that:

[image]

**Hint 2:** I want to create sth. like that:

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526682/197451

Comment: Yes, that could help. But I asked myself: How to change the default (which is these green lines) into curly braces....

Answer (score 2):

Does this satisfy your requirement --

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[edges=none, box={colback=white}]{
parent{
g[id=child1]{first child}
c[id=child2]{second child}
c[id=child3]{third child}
p[id=father]{father}
%p{mother}
}
}
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,raise=3pt},
line width=4pt,yshift=0pt,green] (child1.north west) -- (child3.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Making custom edges is given at page 211 of the `genealogy` manual however modifying it for braces someone has to do it I am still a novice

[image]

Comment: This is a solution as annotation, thx for that. Maybe there is a solution with `edges`, `custom` too, which change the default style.

Comment: please see edit in the answer above

Comment: Yes, thx again, I have that on my own monitor too at this moment: `/gtr/edge/custom={hdowni}{hupi}{hlefti}{hrighti}`, p. 211 in  the genealogytree manual. ;)